# Cannot send image files from Messages using AppleScript on Monterey

Tags: applescript, messages, monterey

After upgrading to Monterey, I can't send image files through Messages using AppleScript. The script below worked before I upgraded to Monterey. I think it's some sort of privileges/sandbox bug and Messages can't access and send a file. Any solutions to the problem?

```
on run
    tell application "Messages"
        set targetService to 1st account whose service type = iMessage
        set targetBuddy to participant "MyPhoneNumber" of targetService
        
        
        send POSIX file "/Users/MyUserName/Desktop/example.jpg" to targetBuddy
        #send "hello" to targetBuddy
        #sending text messages works, sending image files no longer works
        
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Running into same issue – would love suggestions!

Comment: I haven't found a solution to the problem and reported this as a bug to the Apple

Comment: Thanks @Gintaras. If there's a link to the bug report would you mind posting it? I've also verified that giving the Messages app full disk access doesn't solve it

Comment: The link to the bug report is private, a form filled using "Feedback Assistant" recommended by https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ under category: "Incorrect/Unexpected Behavior", "Messages.app", "Sending or receiving"

Comment: @Gintaras. It has been 9 months.  Did you ever hear anything back from apple or find a workaround?

Comment: @Questionmark nope, i feel like they rarely respond.

Comment: I'm running Monterey and I don't have this issue. You can try my script and see if it works for you, though it's much longer/involved of a script: https://gist.github.com/hepcat72/6b7abd9000e8b108ecdb76e12da1257e

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why this is, but I'm only able to get it to work if the image is in the /Users/MyUserName/Pictures folder.